# How to pull google sheet as html element

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets-api

I have very little understanding of web development. I am getting live data from Wikipedia in my google sheet using importhtml function.
On this Google Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l3s5xz_GlJL8vMWrD4NNaCBqsBYmWVxFhLJs0jIK-V4/

I am searching for a few days now for this solution. But can't find or may be can't understand anything. What I am trying to do is pull my google sheet data into a html webpage format like this:

"Despacito"
Luis Fonsi featuring Daddy Yankee
3.79
January 12, 2017

"See You Again"[11]
Wiz Khalifa featuring Charlie Puth
3.12
April 6, 2015

And so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to do your project for you but this information will certainly help.

[Read data from Sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)

The Sheets API allows you to read values from cells, ranges, sets of ranges and entire sheets. The examples on this page illustrate how some common read operations can be achieved with the [spreadsheets.values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values) collection of this API. You can also read cell values using the [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) method, but in most cases using [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) or [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) is easier to use.

To get you started quickly, try the [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).